# Why chi-square test can be used to check a significant difference between the expected frequencies and the observed frequencies?

Tags: chi-squared

I know how chi-square distribution comes from , and also know how to apply the chi-square test.
However can't figure out why chi-square test can be used to check  a significant difference between the expected frequencies and the observed frequencies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Because the distribution of the chi-squared criterion approaches the chi-squared distribution as the size of the sample grows. The true distribution of this criterion is complex and depends on the base distribution (distribution, concordance to which we are checking). But with large samples, it approaches the chi-squared distribution for any base distribution (it is one of the central limit theorems). Therefore, we may not care about the base distribution and use the chi-squared test universally provided that the size of the sample is enough.